# Line up the "={" inside a table

Tags: tables

I'm just beginning to learn Latex and have run into some trouble in a table im trying to create. I do get everything in place, but its not lining up very nicely. Below you see my chaotic code for this table, hope you dont mind the Swedish =)

```
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Variabler}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Names and stuff}                \\

$\text{Kön}= \begin{cases}1, & \text{om patienten är man}\\0, 
& \text{om patienten är kvinna}\end{cases}$ 
& $\text{IVA}= \begin{cases}1, & \text{om patienten har IVA}\\0, 
& \text{om     patienten ej har IVA}\end{cases}$  \\
$\text{VRI}= \begin{cases}1, & \text{om patienten har VRI}\\0, 
& \text{om     patienten ej har VRI}\end{cases}$ 
&  $\text{CVK}=     \begin{cases}1, & \text{om patienten har CVK}\\0, 
& \text{om patienten ej har CVK}\end{cases}$\\
$\text{Something longer}= \begin{cases}1, & \text{om patienten har something longer }\\0, 
& \text{om patienten ej har something longer}\end{cases}$   
&  \\
&  \\
&  \\
& 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your code snippet to small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. help us to help you!

Comment: I will keep that in mind in the future, but will mark this solved now since Zarko have solved my question =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions and observations: (i) Use a two-column `array` environment, not a `tabular` environment; that way, the material will be in math mode automatically. (ii) I wouldn't align the fifth and final `cases` group with any of the others; instead; I'd use a `\multicolumn{2}{l}{...}` construct to let the final `cases` group span both columns of the `array` environment. (iii) Load the `booktabs` package and use its `\addlinespace` directive to create a bit more (vertical) whitespace between the `cases` groups. (iv) To make sure that the `array` environment fits inside the text block, eliminate the left- and right-hand whitespace padding, and reduce the amount of whitespace between the two columns of the `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float,amsmath,caption,booktabs}
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt} % default value: 5pt
\centering
\caption{Variabler}
$\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\text{Names and stuff}} \\
\begin{aligned}
  \text{Kön}&= \begin{cases}1,\text{ om patienten är man}\\
               0,\text{ om patienten är kvinna}  \end{cases} \\
  \addlinespace
  \text{VRI}&= \begin{cases}1,\text{ om patienten har VRI}\\
               0,\text{ om patienten ej har VRI} \end{cases}
\end{aligned} & 
\begin{aligned}
  \text{IVA}&= \begin{cases}1,\text{ om patienten har IVA}\\
               0,\text{ om patienten ej har IVA} \end{cases} \\ 
  \addlinespace
  \text{CVK}&= \begin{cases}1,\text{ om patienten har CVK}\\
               0,\text{ om patienten ej har CVK} \end{cases}\\ 
\end{aligned}\\ 
\addlinespace     
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{%
  \text{Something longer}= 
              \begin{cases}1,\text{ om patienten har something longer }\\
              0,\text{ om patienten ej har something longer} \end{cases}}
\end{array}$
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your table is better balanced (+1)!

Comment: @Zarko - Thanks! :-) (I've already upvoted your answer, BTW.)

Comment: That is also a neat answer, did mark that as "solved" also. In fact depending on what I need in my final table I  might use this solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

like this?

[image]

relevant code snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tabular}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{2}{>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Names and stuff}                \\
\begin{aligned}[t]
\text{Kön}
    & = \begin{cases}
    1, & \text{om patienten är man}\\
    0, & \text{om patienten är kvinna}
        \end{cases}\\
\text{VRI}
    & = \begin{cases}
    1, & \text{om patienten har VRI}    \\
    0, & \text{om patienten ej har VRI}
        \end{cases}\\
\text{Something longer}
    & = \begin{cases}
    1, & \text{om patienten har something longer }\\
    0, & \text{om patienten ej har something longer}
        \end{cases}
\end{aligned}
    &
\begin{aligned}[t]
\text{IVA}
    & = \begin{cases}
    1, & \text{om patienten har IVA}\\
    0, & \text{om patienten ej har IVA}
              \end{cases}  \\
\text{CVK}
    & = \begin{cases}
    1, & \text{om patienten har CVK}\\
    0, & \text{om patienten ej har CVK}
    \end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you provide compilable code?

Comment: uh, of course i can ... but i need to clean-up my math test bed first. done. i was hop, that OP will provide *mwe*, than this is simpler for me ...

Comment: That is exactly how I wanted it, thank you! =)

Answer (score 0):

In a column specification you can provide a `@{content}` spec to mean "insert `content` between these columns".
Here I use it to insert the equals sign between a right and a left aligned column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Variabler}
\begin{tabular}{r@{${}={}$}lr@{${}={}$}l}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Names and stuff}                \\
$\text{Kön}$&$ \begin{cases}1, & \text{om patienten är man}\\0,
& \text{om patienten är kvinna}\end{cases}$
& $\text{IVA}$&$ \begin{cases}1, & \text{om patienten har IVA}\\0,
& \text{om     patienten ej har IVA}\end{cases}$  \\
$\text{VRI}$&$ \begin{cases}1, & \text{om patienten har VRI}\\0,
& \text{om     patienten ej har VRI}\end{cases}$
&  $\text{CVK}$&$     \begin{cases}1, & \text{om patienten har CVK}\\0,
& \text{om patienten ej har CVK}\end{cases}$\\
$\text{Something longer}$&$ \begin{cases}1, & \text{om patienten har something longer }\\0,
& \text{om patienten ej har something longer}\end{cases}$
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You may want to have a look at the many ways `amsmath` provides to align math material, for example the `gather*`, `align*` and `aligned*` environments.

Comment: I made a habit of adding spaces in the tabular parameter: `r @{${}={}$} l r @{${}={}$} l` seems way more pleasant to the eyes in my opinion, and produces the same output. o( ^_^ )o Wow the `{}` add the required spaces around the `=`? I used to use stuff like struts or zero-width boxes for that, haha xD Nice.

Comment: @AliceM. yes the `{}` around `=` forces the interpretation of `=` as a mathrel with operands on the sides, thus including the appropriate mathrel spaces